# Public Partial vs Partial Public?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a **.aspx.vb** file that starts like this:

```
Public Partial Class BlockZonasProduccion
```

I tried creating copy-like of that file, however when I start the declaration of the class, if I type **Public Partial Class class_Name**, it changes automatically to:

```
Partial Public Class class_Name
```

Is there a difference between these two type of Partial classes?
I understand that Partial is used to divide the declaration of a class or structure among several declarations, but still I am new using it.

Comment: It's the same thing, but Visual Studio will sort the modifiers into a standard order for you.

Comment: Also `MustInherit Partial Public Class ClassName`. The order of the modifiers will be fixed by VS as long as the declaration ends with `Class ClassName`.